# Driving high side back-to-back MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I need to make a bidirectional load switch which can work with voltages 0-18V (or as low as possible if 0V isn't feasible) and currents from -3A to 3A and which needs to be able to switch quite fast (ideally 100-200kHz). I have an additional 24V rail (and optionally -10V one) which can be used to power the gate driver. I guess N-channel MOSFET should give better performance (lower Rdson) but that's not too critical.

What sort of driving circuit can I use to control the switch using logic level voltage and should I use common-drain or common-source connection? Are there some commercially available drivers which are powered from separate power rails - I tried searching haven't found anything yet which fits all requirements?

Comment: You seem to be wanting a fast switching solid state relay with back-to-back MOSFETs. Have you looked into this? Would that meet your needs (other than for the switching speed being too low)?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, solid state relay would be a perfect fit if only the switching times would be lower - I checked few and all of them are in the order of milliseconds (0.5ms in the best case)

Comment: Sounds like you just need two p-channel MOSFETs and one logic-level n-channel MOSFET (for driving the gates of the p-channels). I remember reading up that common source is preferred, but I don’t remember why.

Comment: You want common source. two NMOS. High current, low-side Gate driver IC + isolated power supply for it sitting behind a fast optocoupler (or optcoupler alternative like iCoupler which uses transformers).

Comment: @SteKulov I tried both in ltspice and I'm getting better much results (lower switching spikes, faster rise time) with common source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *You seem to be wanting a fast switching solid state relay with
> back-to-back MOSFETs. Have you looked into this? Would that meet your
> needs (other than for the switching speed being too low)? – Andy aka*

> *@Andyaka yes, solid state relay would be a perfect fit if only the
> switching times would be lower - I checked few and all of them are in
> the order of milliseconds (0.5ms in the best case) – igor b.*

The reason why the switching speed is poor is because the optical device used internally is a photo-voltaic generator and, these are slow. Instead, use the same MOSFET topology but utilize a high speed optical MOSFET driver with the addition of a floating supply connected to the common source. Recom and Murata make pretty good isolated DC/DC converters suitable for interfacing with a whole range of opto-MOSFET drivers. This is likely to be your most successful route.

100 kHz switching is pretty normal using this method and, with a little care, 200 kHz shouldn't be a problem.

Of course, if you can live with around 1 ohm on resistance and currents not exceeding around 100 mA then you should be able to find an analogue switch IC that can be powered from the +24 and -10 volt rail. There should be a good few options here. Maybe use both methods in parallel but, reserve the MOSFET method when wanting to switch higher powers.

Comment: Thanks! Few more things: since this would also be used, in some cases, to power some low voltage/low current precision circuitry, would the noise of the isolated DC/DC converter connected to the common source be able to get to  the sensitive parts down the wire?

Since I already have 24V rail (i.e. higher than the max voltage on the line which can also be slightly reduced to have enough headroom to fully turn on the MOSFET) I have a constant feeling like this could be done in a much simpler way with a few components but I didn't have much luck simulating it :).

Comment: @igorb. it might do. All I can say is that the Recom and Murata parts that I have used in the past have around 3 pF isolation capacitance so, if a small noise source fed through 3 pF can upset your sensitive signal then maybe trying to use the 24 volt rail is an option. I would highly recommend that you test the idea using a circuit simulator.  Please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: @igorb. Noise would be a separate question, and, I suspect, as you're already switching the full supply here, the CM noise of a small DC-DC will be the least of your worries. But keep in mind that EMC questions very quickly get quite deep, and you will have to describe your system in large part to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I have two modes of operation, to say, one with fast switching and one with just powering. The source is quite clean (linear regulation after the main DC/DC pre-regulator) and I shouldn't bring additional switching noise. But I like this and will definitely try this approach on PCB. I tried it in simulation and definitely getting the nicest results

Answer (score 1):

Driving with single transformer isn’t possible? For 100kHz the core size can be very small like 15mm ferrite ring with about 3x50 turns.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you simply connect both gates in a bidirectional load switch? In your circuit you always have the body diode losses and you cannot permanently turn on the load.

Comment: @Jens I don’t think the body diode drop can be presented. How?

Comment: @Jens Mind the phasing, both gates are driven together. Synchronous switching will occur, potentially avoiding body drop. I don't understand why they weren't drawn with one secondary though. Michal: consider a series coupling capacitor on the primary (with some RC damping), then a DC-restore network on the secondary. This will work over more PWM range at least, rather than a hard 50%. Beyond that, as the OP hasn't indicated any application, that's probably as good as anything else.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, I didn't properly look at the dots.